# How would I calculate the normals of a wave for lighting?

Tags: directx-11, hlsl

I'm doing vertex manipulation of a plane with DirectX11 and for my lighting (multiple point lights with specularity) I need to recalculate the normals of each vertex.

My question is essentially what equation would I use to do get the normals (x & y) of this wave equation (in HLSL):

```
input.position.y = height * sin(input.position.x + time) * sin(input.position.y + time);
```

Comment: The normal to a point on a surface is a vector that points away from that surface and is perpendicular to the surface at the point.

It appears you are calculating the surface point positions mathematically, so you can rely on the mathematical definition of a surface normal to compute a similar formula for it.  You don't show the formula for the entire position, so we can only guess what the formula should be for *your* surface.

Comment: Try to search for finite differences. Maybe using The computeshader is The Best way to handle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to calculate the tangent to the surface along both x- and y- axis. You can do this at each vertex in the vertex shader. The normal to the vertex is the cross product of the tangent vectors at that vertex.

In order to get the tangents, you need to calculate the derivative of you equation. Your equation is of the form:

```
f(x,y) = a*sin(b*x+t)*sin(c*y+t)
```

Where `a` is the amplitude (or height) of the wave, `b` and `c` are the wave length or period and `t` is the wave's phase. The partial derivatives of such function are:

```
df/dx = a*b*cos(b*x+t)*sin(c*y+t) // tangent equation along x-axis
df/dy = a*c*sin(b*x+t)*cos(c*y+t) // tangent equation along y-axis
```

In your case `a=height`, `b=c=1`. The tangent vectors are:

```
tx = [x, y, df/dx] // tangent vector along x-axis at point (x,y)
ty = [x, y, df/dy] // tangent vector along y-axis at point (x,y)
```

Finally, to calculate the normal you take the cross product of tangent vectors:

```
n = cross(tx,ty)
```

Note that the order of cross product matter. If you switch the order then the result will be `-n`. Evaluating the cross product we get:

```
n = [y*((df/dy)-(df/dx)), x*((df/dx)-(df/dy)), 0]
```

Substituting `df/dx` and `df/dy` in above vector:

```
k = (a*c*sin(b*x+t)*cos(c*y+t) - a*b*cos(b*x+t)*sin(c*y+t))
n = [y*k, x*(-k), 0]
```

So, for your equation we get:

```
k = height*(sin(x+t)*cos(y+t) - cos(x+t)*sin(y+t))
n = [y*k, -x*k, 0]
```

At each vertex, when you put in the x and y coordinates, you'll get the normal vector. I might have made some mistakes in my derivation since my calculus is rusty. But it should be something along these lines.